# Taking arguments as input from terminal

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, arguments

this is part of a function that takes input from terminal and sorts them depending on what the inputs are (sorting type, a version/variation of the sorting method to use, and the size of the array). This is what I have so far:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) { //will have 3 arguments not including function name: sortingtype, version and arr size
    int * arr = make_arr(argv[2], argv[3]); //[2]

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "sortingtype1") == 0) {
        SortingType1(arr, argv[3]); //[2][3]
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[1], "sortingtype2") == 0) {
        SortingType2(arr, argv[3]); //[2][3]
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void test(){ //[1]
    main("sortingtype1", "a", 10); //sortingtype, version and arr size
}
```

[1] I have a function test() to simulate input from terminal but I don't know if it works that way. I get an error saying that there are too many arguments to main.

[2] Whether or not I remove that testing function, I still get warnings about "passing argument *(the arguments with argv[X])* makes integer from pointer without a cast".

[3] These also need to be type int and not type char*, how do I change them?

Any suggestions on how to go about this? I have seen solutions using sscanf, but would prefer a more basic solution around my skill level first for understanding.

Edit: segmentation faults from

```
int * SortingType2(int * arr, int len) {
    for (int i=1; i < len; i++) {
        int x = arr[i];
        int j = i;
        while ((j > 0) && (x < arr[j-1])) {
            arr[j] = arr[j-1];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j] = x;
    }
    return arr;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int size;
    if (argc > 3) size = atoi(argv[3]);

    int * arr = make_arr(argv[2][0], size);

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "sortingtype1") == 0) {
        SortingType1(arr, size);
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[1], "sortingtype2") == 0) {
        SortingType2(arr, size);
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not supposed to call `main` directly. That is basic C that is taught in the first lesson of any tutorial or text book. Please consult those.

Comment: `sscanf` is a good choice for converting a string to an `int`. The other options are `strtol` and `atoi`. `strtol` is a little obtuse in the way it handles error checking. `atoi` simply doesn't bother. `sscanf` is the middle ground, with decent error checking that's easy to use.

Comment: @kaylum-- a small quibble. The C standard certainly allows recursive calls to `main()`.

Comment: @kaylum: Are you confused between C++ and C?  In C++, it is not allowed to call `main()` (see [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c) for the details).  In C, there is no prohibition against calling `main()` — it is a normal function that can be called by the user's code, and the only thing special about it is that in a hosted environment, it is the function called by the startup code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I knew someone would make that point :-)  I was just too lazy to go into the details. I really meant to say there is no need to explicitly call `main` like that and that the `test` function will never be called as it is shown anyway.

Comment: @kaylum: I'm glad I helped meet your expectations :D   You're right that the code shown won't call `test()` — but the `make_arr()` and `sortingType1()` and `sortingType2()` functions could, in theory (but probably not in practice) do so.

Comment: What are you passing in `argv[2]`, and what is the function `make_arr()` doing?

Comment: @DavidBowling `argv[2]` is a version of the sorting type (given from `argv[1]`) to use. So if `argv[2]` is "a", for example, that might mean a given array sorted already. "b" might mean it's a scrambled array. `make_arr()` makes the array for the sorted array.

Comment: First, move the `return` statement out of the `else` clause and to the end of `main()`. You will get segfaults if you don't pass enough arguments, so you should have something like: `if (argc < 4) { printf("Usage:...."); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}`, so that the program bails instead of segfaulting.Try this, and we'll go from there.

Comment: I made the suggested changes to your code and put it at the end of my answer below so that you can see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argv[]` is an array of strings, so you need to convert them if you want integers. The simplest way to do this is with `atoi()` or `sscanf()`. `atoi()` is in `stdlib.h`, and `sscanf()` is in `stdio.h`. With `atoi()`, you just give it a string, and it returns an `int`. With `sscanf()`, you provide a string, conversion specifiers, and addresses of variables, just as in the `scanf()` function, the difference being that here you are scanning a string instead of stdin. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // needed for atoi()
#include <stdlib.h>  // needed for sscanf()

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    /* if argv[1] exists, convert to int */
    if (argc > 1)
        i = atoi(argv[1]);

    /* if argv[2] exists, convert to int */
    if (argc > 2)
        sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &j);

    printf("%d -- %d\n", i, j);

    return 0;
}
```

If you compile this code and execute it you get, for example:

```
david scratch λ> ./a.out 123 456
123 -- 456
```

Working with your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int size;

    if (argc < 4) {
        printf("Usage: %s sortingType state size\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    size = atoi(argv[3]);

    int * arr = make_arr(argv[2], size);

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "sortingtype1") == 0) {
        SortingType1(arr, size);
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[1], "sortingtype2") == 0) {
        SortingType2(arr, size);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used atoi but am getting segmentation fault when executing now. Tried declaring variables and using them in place of argv[X] and tried simply wrapping them inside atoi().

Comment: Can you update your question with a good example of the code that is failing for you?

Comment: Okay it seems to be an issue with the arguments then (I used Jonathan Leffer's first code): `Usage: sortingtype sortingType state size`

Comment: If I comment out your function calls to `make_arr()`, `SortingType1()`, and `SortingType2()` in the code I just showed above, no problems. I think that your trouble is in one of these functions. I would first look at `make_arr()`.

Comment: Hmm that is so strange! I actually did that earlier to make sure it's not involving those functions, and commented them out again, and am still getting the seg fault. I will take a good look again in the morning when I'm not so tired. Thanks.

Comment: I think it was a problem with Jonathan's code. I changed `main(3, argv);` to `main(4, argv);` and `char *argv[] = { "sortingtype", "a", "10", 0 };` to `char *argv[] = { 0, "sortingtype", "a", "10" };` and no seg fault now.

Comment: I didn't realize that you were trying to use the `test()` function, calling `main()`. If you pass 3 arguments, then `argc` will be 4, but the way I have seen it, when you call `main()` you do `main(argc - 1, argv)`. This is what Jonathan had. Are you null-terminating the `argv` array?

Comment: I'm no longer using the test function, just testing from terminal now. You were right about seg faults from calling functions too. Updated with an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call `main()` from a function, then you have to pass an argument count and a pointer to an array of strings that is null terminated (see [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c) for the details).

Thus, you might write:

```
void test(void)
{
    char *argv[] = { "sortingtype", "a", "10", 0 };
    main(3, argv);
}
```

It is not common to do this.  There is no evidence in your code of the `test()` function being called.

Note that the arguments are not modifiable strings in the code shown above; normally, the arguments are modifiable.  If that's going to matter, you have to work a bit harder:

```
void test(void)
{
    char arg0[] = "sortingtype";
    char arg1[] = "a";
    char arg2[] = "10";
    char *argv[] = { arg0, arg1, arg2, 0 };
    main(3, argv);
}
```

Note too that all the arguments in `argv` should be strings.  Your original code seemed to try to pass `10` rather than `"10"` but that is not allowed in the argument vector (though `10` could be valid as the argument count, of course).

---

Please note that calling `main()` recursively is an eccentric thing to do at best.  It is seldom actually necessary, or desirable.  It is, however, legal in C — but it is not legal in C++.

Comment: To be complete, this answer needs to provide the solution to this simple conundrum: since the startup code calls `main`, the only way that `test` can call `main` is if `main` calls `test`. But if `test` is calling a `main` that calls `test`, then you're necessarily not testing the `main` that you intended to test.

Comment: You said: _The only way that `test` can call `main` is if `main` calls `test`._   That statement is incomplete; the full statement should be: _The only way that `test()` can call `main()` is if `main()` calls `test()`, or a function called by (a function called by …) `main()` in turn calls `test()`._  You need conditional code somewhere to prevent infinite recursion, of course.  I've used a recursive call to `main()` once, in a test program.  It isn't an every day usage.

Comment: Please note that calling main from the application itself is very bad practice. As is recursion, most of the time.

Comment: @Lundin: fair comment — I've added a more or less suitable note.